# Wait for TinyMCE to load

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have these two lines of code one after another.

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'email_body');
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data.tplCustom.htmltemplate);
```

Second line tries to set content even before the tinymce is done . I think cause of that I am getting " tinyMCE.activeEditor is null" error.

Is there any way to wait until its loaded ? Thanks

Answer (score 65):

Version 4 of TinyMCE uses a slightly different event binding method.

**Version 3**

```
// v3.x
tinymce.init({
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
            console.debug('Editor is done: ' + ed.id);
        });
    }
});
```

**Version 4**

```
// v4.x
tinymce.init({
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('init', function(args) {
            console.debug(args.target.id);
        });
    }
});
```

Reference: 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onInit
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x

Comment: Booya, that was it. Thank you.

Comment: Huge thanks, this helped me so much after searching for over 1 hour.

Answer (score 11):

If you cannot access to the `tinymce.init({...})` declaration (like in *WordPress* for example), you can also use `addeditor` event :

```
  /// Fires when an editor is added to the EditorManager collection.
  tinymce.on('addeditor', function( event ) {
    var editor = event.editor;
    var $textarea = $('#' + editor.id);
    console.log($textarea.val());
  }, true );
```

[TinyMCE 'addeditor' event documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editormanager/#addeditor)

Comment: The bloody WordPress tinymce editor load has been driving me nuts. Thx so much for this. 