# JSFiddle + TinyMCE + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, jsfiddle, tinymce-4

I'm experiencing an issue trying to use tinymce API inside an angular directive in JSFiddle.
Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/RamanChodzka/a8dUp/34/)
The tinymce editor is initialised just fine, there's no errors in browser console. But I get 'undefined' if I try to get an instance of the tinymce Editor.
The question is: why does `tinymce.get(id);` result in `undefined`?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <my-editor ng-model="text"></my-editor>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.directive('myEditor', function () {
    var uniqueId = 0;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: true,
        template: '<textarea></textarea>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var id = 'myEditor_' + uniqueId++;
            element.find('textarea').attr('id', id);
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#' + id
            });

            var editor = tinymce.get(id);
            alert(editor); **// why is this undefined?**
        }
    }
});
```

I've also played with options in Frameworks & Extensions section of JSFiddle. But with no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait for TinyMCE to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408559/wait-for-tinymce-to-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with the issue, where the elements have not been appended to the dom when you are doing your alert.  (look at the html in firebug)

```
<my-editor ng-model="text" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <textarea id="myEditor_0"></textarea>
</my-editor>
```

Placing the alert inside of a `setTimeout` will allow you to `alert()` the object.

```
setTimeout(function(){
     var editor = tinymce.get(id);
     alert(editor); // why is this undefined?
},0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to go is to set the [init_instance_callback option](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:init_instance_callback) in `tinyMCE.init`  or in `tinymceOptions` if you are using [angular-ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce) :

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
  init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
     MyCtrl.editor=editor
     console.log("Editor: " + editor.id + " is now initialized.");
     editor.on('Change', function(editor, e) {
        MyCtrl.func()
     });             
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, browsing the internet about fetching this editor in angular to call uploadImages function on it and spent huge time on it

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer Mark gave:

You will need to wait for the editor to get initalized and ready to be usable.
For this you may use the onInit tinymce handler. onInit gets fired when the editor is ready.