# How to set callback to execute after all the tinyMCE editors have been initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I've loaded a tinyMCE editor using `wp_editor` function of Wordpress.

Now, I want to set value of that editor after it gets initialized. I tried to do it like this:

```
$(function() {
    tinymce.get(...).setContent(...);
});
```

But it throws an error saying `Cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined` because the editor has not been initialized. To confirm it I console logged using `console.log( tinymce.editors.length )` statement and it prints `0` but later when I inspected the variable `tinymce.editors` using browser console after the loading was done, the editor was there and I could manipulate it.

So, my conclusion was to wait for all the tinyMCE editors to be initialized then run the above code to change the editor's value. Note that I need to set the value using JS, not from the backend (php).

Please tell me if there's a way to accomplish this. And ask me if you need more information or I'm unclear.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for TinyMCE to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408559/wait-for-tinymce-to-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the specific editor manager to get added and then bind the `init` event handler to set content of the editor like this:

```
tinymce.on( 'addeditor', e => {
    if ( e.editor.id === <your_editor_id> ) {
        e.editor.on( 'init', event => {
            event.target.setContent( <your_editor_content> );
        });
    }
}, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can populate TinyMCE after it's been initialized using the [setup](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) option in the editor config. For example:

```
setup: function (editor) {
  editor.on('init', function (e) {
    editor.setContent('<p>Hello world!</p>');
  });
}
```

Try passing in these editor settings when you call wp_editor().

Resources:

- [How to get content and set content in TinyMCE](http://See%20https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/.)

Comment: i'm not using `tinymce.init` method to initialize the editor. If I had, I wouldn't have this problem. I'm using `wp_editor` function of wordpress.

Comment: Yes, but I think there's a way to pass these settings in to the editor when you call wp_editor(). For example, see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48356/creating-a-wp-editor-instance-with-custom-tinymce-buttons